# Passing a string to a Userform

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a simple Userform with a single text box with scroll bars for informational messages.

Unfortunately, I'm getting a Run-time Error 438, Object doesn't support this properly or method error.

My testing code is simple
'three different attempts

Userform including different attempts

```
 Dim inString As String
 Sub txtBoxVal(passedStr As String)
    inString = passedStr
    MyMessageBox = inString
 End Sub

 public Property get txtBoxVal2(passedStr As String) as string
    inString = passedStr
    MyMessageBox = inString
 End Sub

 Public Sub update()

    MyMessageBox.Text = publicStrVarDeclaredInFunction
 End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

 End Sub
```

Sheet1 Code

```
Public publicVar As String

Private Sub userformTest()
Dim myForm As UserForm
Dim testString As String

testString = "This is a test string"

    Set myForm = New MyUserForm
    With myForm
        ' My 3 different way attempts
        Call .txtBoxVal(testString)
        .update publicVar
        Call .txtBoxVal2(testString)
        .Show

    End With
End Sub
```

Anyone have any insights where I'm making my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your Userform's name is `MyUserForm` and `MyMessageBox` is the `TextBox` control:

1. You should `Dim myForm As MyUserForm` instead of `Dim myForm As UserForm`.
2. Your `update` sub does not have an argument but you passed `publicVar` in `.update publicVar`, you will need to declare the argument in your `update` sub like this:

```
Public Sub update(argNewText As String)
   MyMessageBox.Text = argNewText
End Sub
```

3. `Call .txtBoxVal2(testString)` won't work for 2 reason:

   a) `txtBoxVal2` is a `Property`, not a `Sub` so you do not use `Call`. You assign value to `txtBoxVal2` property by `myForm.txtBoxVal2 = "new value"`

   b) `txtBoxVal2` is a `Get` property so you can only retrieve `txtBoxVal2` value, in order to allow `txtBoxVal2` be assigned a value, you have to change to `Let`:

```
Public Property Let txtBoxVal2(passedStr As String)
    inString = passedStr
    MyMessageBox = inString
End Property
```

=====================

I personally prefer to use `Let` property approach in this case so your code will look something like this:

Sheet1

```
Private Sub userformTest()
    Dim testString As String
    testString = "This is a test string"

    Dim myForm As MyUserForm
    Set myForm = New MyUserForm
    myForm.MessageText = testString
    
End Sub
```

MyUserForm

```
Private inString As String

Public Property Let MessageText(passedStr As String)
    inString = passedStr
    MyMessageBox.Text = inString
End Property
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and detailed response!  I managed to misinterpret  the point of other answers I used to get where I did.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Make a simple UserForm called 'MyMsgBox' with a textbox called 'TextBox1' and a command button called 'CmdOK'.

Put this code into the UserForm:

```
Option Explicit

''' On form show:
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

''' Put text into textbox
    TextBox1 = pstMessage
    
'''BEEP (optional)
    Beep

End Sub

''' Close form on OK
Private Sub CmdOK_Click(): Unload Me
End Sub
```

Put this code in any Standard Module:

```
Option Explicit

    Public pstMessage$

Sub ShowMsg()

''' Put the message into pstMessage
    pstMessage = "This is a test string"

''' Run MyMsgBox
    MyMsgBox.Show

End Sub
```